# ReadableBytechannel.read always returns -1

Tags: java, io, nio

I am using ReadableByteChannel to read from a file.

The code snippet is as below

```
   InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Copy.tiff");
   FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream("Copy.tiff");
   FileChannel inChannel = in1.getChannel();
   ReadableByteChannel srcChannel = null;
   srcChannel = Channels.newChannel(in);
   ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
   long pos1 = 0;
   buffer.rewind();
   pos1= srcChannel.read(buffer);//Here value is -1
   pos1 = inChannel.read(buffer);//Here some positive number
```

If I use InputStream read method always returns -1.
If I use FileInputStream it returns a positive number.
Googling did not provide any appropriate answer.
Any feedback on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this (on Windows). I get a positive value via both methods, and I don't see why it should fail. Maybe it's some awful implementation-dependent quirk.

FileChannel (as returned by FileInputStream.getChannel()) already implements ReadableByteChannel, so I wonder why you're creating one manually?

Comment: My need was to create a generic ReadableChannel.
When I observed ReadableByteChannel was failing, i tried with FileChannel.

Comment: But FileChannel *is* a ReadableByteChannel.

Comment: The input may be a Byte array, input stream or a file input stream. So i am constructing a ReadableByteChannel which can handle all the three.

Comment: @user330482 But, I repeat, a FileChannel *is* a ReadableByteChannel. You don't have to jump through all those hoops. You just have to write `ReadableByteChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream("Copy.tiff).getChannel();`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine for me:

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Copy.tiff");
    ReadableByteChannel srcChannel = Channels.newChannel(in);
    long pos = srcChannel.read(buffer);
    System.out.println("Position in channel: " + pos);
```

Comment: Probalby an OS dependent issue. It is not reproducible on linux,but on one of the windows machines i can reproduce.

Comment: Yes, OS and/or JDK implementation. I can't confirm for Windows as I don't have access to that right now, but I believe @Boann got a positive test on his system. What JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadableByteChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream("Copy.tiff).getChannel();
```